# tokio::join on mapped futures that return trait types has the error "implementation of `FnOnce` is not general enough"

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-futures

I have started multiple tasks with `tokio::spawn` and I want to collect the reasons why they exited as `dyn std::error::Error`.

If any of the tasks panic, I want to forward the panic instantly without waiting for the other tasks. To achieve this, I used `futures::map` to unwrap the `tokio::JoinHandle` while propagating panics.

Then I used `tokio::join!` to wait simultaneously on all futures.

```
use futures::FutureExt;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        foo().await;
    })
    .await
    .unwrap();
}

async fn foo() {
    // Start two tasks.
    let worker1 = tokio::spawn(bar(1)).map(|res| res.unwrap());
    let worker2 = tokio::spawn(bar(2)).map(|res| res.unwrap());

    // Wait for all started tasks at once.
    // This doesn't compile.
    let (error1, error2) = tokio::join!(worker1, worker2);

    // This does compile, but panics only after 5 seconds.
    // let error1 = worker1.await;
    // let error2 = worker2.await;

    // Ignore in this example.
    let _: Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send> = error1;
    let _: Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send> = error2;
}

async fn bar(id: u8) -> Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send> {
    if id == 1 {
        tokio::time::sleep(core::time::Duration::from_secs(5)).await;
        Box::new(std::io::Error::last_os_error())
    } else {
        panic!("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

It gives me a compilation error:

```
error: implementation of `FnOnce` is not general enough
 --> src/main.rs:5:5
  |
5 |     tokio::spawn(async move {
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ implementation of `FnOnce` is not general enough
  |
  = note: closure with signature `fn(Result<Box<(dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + '0)>, JoinError>) -> Box<dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send>` must implement `FnOnce<(Result<Box<(dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + '1)>, JoinError>,)>`, for any two lifetimes `'0` and `'1`...
  = note: ...but it actually implements `FnOnce<(Result<Box<dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send>, JoinError>,)>`
```

I am building with `rustc 1.56.1 (59eed8a2a 2021-11-01)`.
My Cargo.toml has:

```
tokio = { version = "1.12", features = ["full"] }
futures = "0.3"
```

I'm looking to understand this error or at least find an alternative solution.

Comment: Have you already read [Implementation of FnOnce is not general enough in async fn?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64320590/155423)?

Comment: As a practical immediate workaround, you can probably use a `select` instead of a join.

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/89976; https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/71723 and https://users.rust-lang.org/t/weird-error-with-tokio-try-join-and-mapped-futures/66216/12

Comment: @Shepmaster It seems to be a similar problem to the issues you linked.

Comment: @Shepmaster how would using select work? I would get panic forwarding but I could only get one of the results if they didn't panic.

Comment: You would need to select repeatedly with all the values. Likely using fused futures and a loop.